# How to setup AWS Cloudfront for Magento 2

Tags: header, ssl, apache2, cloudfront-cdn

I have been looking everywhere for a solution, and I was following the following documents to achieve this task.

https://absolutecommerce.co.uk/magento2-aws-cloudfront-cdn

Here they mention something about, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.magento.website.com`. I am assuming my issue is something to do with this.

Since I am new to this configuration stuff, its has become a trial and error war so far. This is what I have so far,

1. Have a Magento installation, on AWS ec2 with a ELB with a SSL certificate associated with it (example.com, *.example.com),
2. Have cloud formation set up with the same certificate used for the ELB. This is only HTTPS. DNS set up to cdn.example.com.

My Apache configuration is as below,

```
VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined


        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
                RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
        </Directory>


        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

when I request a object,

https://cdn.example.com/static/version1485641847/frontend/Venustheme/superstore/en_US/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css

it gives a 404. I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Have you set up the cloud front origin properly?  The way cloudfront works is that if it doesn't have a local cache it requests it from your defined origin and caches that.  If your origin is returning a 404 then Cloudfront will return a 404 or error.  Did you deploy your static resources on your web server first before testing?

Comment: @Brett after some times,  I noticed that there is part missing in the url. which is /pub/media, and /pub/static/ so now the origin images and js can be accessed, but now with the new cdn sub domain, I get, net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue, it was the URLs `base_static_url` and `base_media_url`

I was following a tutorial and assumed that magento is very opinionated in terms of url and stuff, But the case is different, it is different.

I specified urls as https://cdn.example.com/media/, https://cdn.example.com/static/. But what should have been was, 
 https://cdn.example.com/pub/media/ and https://cdn.example.com/pub/static/

There is also some configuration pitfalls in both cloud front and apache configurations